# Mysql: Trying to update a cost from a table of many costs

Tags: mysql

I have an Inventory Transaction Summary table (tran) containing stock, date, qty and cost.  The Primary key is stock and date; the date field is a normal key.  Issues are negative and receipts are positive.  The cost value changes on every receipt.  To find the current cost for a stock number (or for any date) is simple and virtually instantaneous:

```
select cost from tran 
  where stock = 12345 AND date <= 20140518
    order by date desc limit 1;
```

My problem is trying to view a status report for any period of time:

```
create temp 
  (stock int primary key,qty int,cost decimal(9,2));

insert into temp(stock,qty,cost)
  select stock,sum(qty),cost from tran 
   where date <= 20140430 
     group by stock order by date desc;
```

The Stock Status qty is correct, the cost is not.  I have tried many methods to get a distinct cost and the only way that works:

```
create temp2
  (stock2 int primary key,cost2 decimal(9,3));

insert ignore into temp2 
  select stock,cost from tran
    where date <= 20140430 order by date desc;

update temp inner join temp2 
  on stock = stock2 set cost = cost2;
```

The "insert ignore" takes a very long time. Is there a method of doing this using joins or sub-queries? The actual production table exceeds one million records, the temp table above is 1900 records and the temp2 table is 14000 (the actual number of different inventory items).

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Regards

Ed Sharp

Comment: You need to further explain the distinct cost you are trying to retrieve.  Is it an average, the last cost entered, or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to get the `stock`, `sum(qty)` and most recent `cost` by date?  If so, one option is to use a correlated subquery:

```
insert into temp(stock,qty,cost)
select t.stock,
   sum(t.qty), 
   (select cost from tran t2 where t2.stock = t.stock and t2.date = max(t.date))
from tran t
where t.date <= 20140430 
group by t.stock 
order by t.date desc;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19765/1)

You could also use something similar to your original query:

```
insert into temp(stock,qty,cost)
select t.stock,
   sum(t.qty), 
   (select cost 
    from tran t2 
    where t2.stock = t.stock and 
       t2.date <= 20140430 
    order by t2.date desc
    limit 1)
from tran t
where t.date <= 20140430 
group by t.stock 
order by t.date desc;
```

By the way, your first attempt isn't working correctly because you aren't grouping by the cost and mysql is returning an arbitrary value.  Most other RDBMS require all fields in the select statement to be defined in the group by or in an aggregate.

Comment: Thank you for you very quick response.  Your solution was exactly on track and just what I was looking for.  With 980,000 records, the temp table was created in just 2.6 seconds.  I had thought of a sub_query but had no idea of how to do it.  Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the cost for the period of time.  The first idea that comes to mind is `avg()`:

```
  select stock, sum(qty), avg(cost)
  from tran 
  where date <= 20140430 
  group by stock
  order by date desc;
```

Or, perhaps a weighted average:

```
  select stock, sum(qty), sum(cost * qty) / sum(qty)
  from tran 
  where date <= 20140430 
  group by stock
  order by date desc;
```

If these don't work, update your question with sample data and the results that you want.